# What is monotonic classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I read this about student surveys:

> Student surveys occupy a central place in the evaluation of courses at
>   teaching institutions. At the end of each course, students are
>   requested to evaluate various aspects such as activities, methodology,
>   coordination or resources used. In addition, a final qualification is
>   given to summarize the quality of the course. The prediction of this
>   final qualification can be accomplished by using monotonic
>   classification techniques.

Then it introduces the existence of a *monotonic k-nearest neighbors* algorithm (which I didn't even know it existed), but in a nutshell, what does it mean with **monotonic classification**? How does it differ from standard classification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition**

Monotonic classification is a classification where the dataset is monotonic.

From what I understood, I'll explain briefly what a monotonic dataset is.

---

**Monotonic dataset**

We can write any object $x$ of a dataset as a $n$-dimentional vector:

$x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ where all $x_{i<n}$ are the *attributes* and $x_n$ is the *class* of $x$.

A dataset $D$ will be monotonic if, for any $x, y \in D$, it follows that:

$$x_i \le y_i \Leftrightarrow x_n \le y_n \quad\forall i\small < n$$

That is, if all attributes of $x$ are less or equal than all correspondent attributes of $y$, then their classes will also be.

---

**And what about the outliers?**

Obviously there can be outliers in such dataset, for example, let $D$ be a dataset where each element $x$ stores the score of an student in $n-1$ exams and $x_n$ stores the mean. This dataset is clearly monotonic, given that if a student get greater scores than another student in all exams (which are the attributes), then the former's mean will also be greater than the latter's

Suppose $n=4$. Let $x=(\small 1,2,3,$ $2)$ and $y = (\small3,1,5,$ $3)$. We can't say that $x_i \le y_i$ and we can't say $y_i \le x_i$ completely, so we say these elements *cannot be compared*, although $x_n \le y_n$. This is an example of the behaviour of outliers in a monotonic dataset.

---

**Example of monotonic classifier: Monotonic Nearest Neighbor**

If a classification algorithm is able to deal with such datasets, it is a *monotonic classifier*.

An example is the *Monotonic Nearest Neighbor*. Given a monotonic dataset $D$, to classify an object $x$, it iterates through $D$ and computes:

$c_{min} = max\{y_n |\; y \in D \land y_i \le x_i\}$ $\quad \quad \quad$ (if $x$ and $y$ are not comparable, skip that $y$)

$c_{max} = min\{y_n |\; y \in D \land y_i \ge x_i\}$

Then, it finds an element $z \in D$ such that $z_n \in [c_{min}, c_{max}]$ and the distance from $x$ to $z$ is minimum, that is, there will be no $y \in D$ with $y_n \in [c_{min}, c_{max}]$ whose distance to $x$ is smaller then the distance from $z$ to $x$.

Finally, $x$ will be classified as $z_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe monotonic *regression* is used with Likert Scale information and so someone might refer to it as classification instead of regression because a Likert scale is categorical. Sort of like a Logistic regression is a classification method.